# Angular - Set variables of class empty and object memory after re-new

Tags: angular, class, memory

I have a class with a lot of variables inside.

I initialize the class like this :

```
_ptPassage: PointPassage = new PointPassage;
```

The public variables of this class are empty, but they'll get assigned eventually.

At some point I want to reset the variables to what they were after the `new`.
Currently what I'm doing is :

```
this._ptPassage = null;
this._ptPassage = new PointPassage;
```

Could you tell me a better way if there is ?
And I would like to know if I do a `new` again without nullifying first:

```
this._ptPassage = new PointPassage;
```

Does that free the previous allocation automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: i did not understand why you are calling the constructor of `PointPassage` like this `this._ptPassage = new PointPassage;
` , can you explain please ?

Comment: I'm new to angular, so maybe i'm doing it wrong, but the point is I want the variables of my class to be reset. Because in my form I don't want for example _ptPassage.idPointPassage to be equal to 0 but to be empty. And for the moment that's how I'm doing it

Comment: you can use the constructor like this without nullifying first :  `this._ptPassage = new PointPassage();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of class  instance creation is

```
 this._ptPassage = new PointPassage();
```

And yes, you can reassign variable without previous resetting to null.